# Advanced custom fields - Can't get all the fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Haven't used this in a while and not sure if this is right. I have a few custom fields with the same key. For example:

```
weapon -> {"name": "Club"}
weapon -> {"name": "Bow"}
```

Using this example: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/ I'm trying:

```
echo($post->ID);
$values = get_fields($post->ID);
var_dump($values);
```

But it returns `24bool(false)`. The post id is there but no custom fields. I tried with unique keys like weapon1, weapon2 just to test but it doesn't fix my problem.

What I would like to do is get all custom fields for any key and display them in a loop.

Something like `$values = get_fields("weapon", $post->ID);`
Doing this only returns one value. I currently have two with same key.

How can this be done?

Comment: From what I can see is that, maybe, because you have two fields with the same same it causes problems. Either  try giving them different names or, if available, use repeater field.

Comment: I tried giving them different names. Ideally it should work with same name. I don't want to add and remove weapons from a json.

Comment: Did it work with different names?. Check [this post](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/same-name-for-fields-in-the-same-group/) about same name fields

Comment: No `get_fields()` didn't work with different names. Returns `bool(false)`. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Most likely the post that you used to check the fields didn't have any values. Try adding the values and updating the post, after that try again.

Comment: No ... it has values. It's ok. Thank you for your help. Maybe this plugin isn't the best solution for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What kind of field is this? Select, checkboxes? `get_fields("weapon", $post->ID);` won't work because it needs to be `get_fields([$post_id], [$format_value]);`. `get_field();` can store an array, what does `get_field("weapon", $post->ID);` return?